# Ask for unlock pattern - Android

Tags: android, unlock, android-security

Is there a way, I can ask a user for perform the unlock operation on his phone using the set pattern(passcode, fingerprint, etc) to access certain features of my application?

For example, in iOS, I generate an OTP based on a QR code. I can ask the user for the unlock pin before showing him the generated OTP token. I want the same for my android application. This prevents the misuse of the application.

Comment: Have you found a backport solution?

Comment: @Beloo: No, I did not find anything for API below Lollipop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create that intent with the `KeyguardManager` class, using the [createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method available since API 21, it should be called from your activity with the `startActivityForResult(intent)` method.

In your activity:

```
private static final int CREDENTIALS_RESULT = 4342; //just make sure it's unique within your activity.

void checkCredentials() {
  KeyguardManager keyguardManager = this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
  Intent credentialsIntent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Password required", "please enter your pattern to receive your token");
  if (credentialsIntent != null) {
    startActivityForResult(credentialsIntent, CREDENTIALS_RESULT);
  } else {
    //no password needed
    doYourThing();
  }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Bundle data) {
  if (requestCode == CREDENTIALS_RESULT) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      //hoorray!
      doYourThing();
    } else {
      //uh-oh
      showSomeError();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at this. I am also looking for a solution compatible from API level 16.