# Ask user to confirm screen lock

Tags: android, security, design-patterns, locking, lockscreen

**I need to implement the `Confirm screen lock screen` in my app**

On some event, like click on button I want to invoke the confirm screen lock like used in Google login and Paytm app:
[image]

I have checked on multiple site but did not find any solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ask for unlock pattern - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629634/ask-for-unlock-pattern-android)

Comment: That is for api 21 and above. I need for api 9

Comment: In this case you should mention that in initial question. But for this defined question i think unfortunately it isn't possible with older api's

Comment: I have not even mentioned for api 21 and above